# Difference between "to nick" vs "to clip"?

Tags: word-usage

Can anyone tell me the difference between "clip" and "nip"? Both mean to cut something. In English, there are too many words to describe cutting (crop, cut, nip, split, cut, clip) I'm always so confused.

Comment: Do you want *nick* v *clip* (title) or *nip* v *clip* (question)?

Answer (score 2):

“Clip” to me means “to cut short”, as in nails or a beard. It can also be used to describe film editing- as in clipping a video to make it shorter.

“Nip” is not a word I’d normally use in American English; before looking it up I thought “to nip at” meant “to take small bites of”, but since I looked it up I see it can also mean “to pinch” or “to sever [cut off] (as if) by pinching sharply”.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nip

Answer (score 2):

To 'clip' can mean to give a glancing blow during movement past something, e.g. someone fired a gun at me, but it just clipped (grazed) my ear. To nip, as Mixolydian says, means to takes small bites (a puppy nips) or pinch, or sever (gripping or wire cutting pliers are sometimes called 'nippers' in Britain). I wonder if the OP is thinking about 'nick' which, as well as meaning 'cut a notch out of something', can have the passing-blow, grazing meaning of 'clip'. The bullet only nicked me.